# segmentation fault in iterator of std::list

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, stdlist

class declarations

```
struct cmp_str
{
 bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b)
 {
    return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
 }
};

class event_t {
public:
  event_t(String *_session_time, String *_event_type, String *_table_name, String *_num_of_events);
  ~event_t();
   char *table_name;
   char *event_type;  
   pthread_mutex_t lock;
   pthread_cond_t cond;
   int num_of_events_threshold;
   double time_out; 
   int num_of_events_so_far; 
};  
std::map <char*, std::list<event_t*>, cmp_str > all_events;  //global map
```

I have this function which waits for a variable to reach for a certain threshold which is done through pthread_cond and pthread_mutex. It then returns. The last line gives segmentation fault.

```
void foo(){
    //don't worry event object ic created properly
    event_t *new_event = new event_t(args[0]->val_str(s),(args[1]->val_str(s)), (args[2]->val_str(s)), (args[3]->val_str(s)));

    map<char*, list<event_t*> >::iterator map_it;  
    map_it = all_events.find(new_event->table_name);

    if(map_it == all_events.end()){
      list<event_t*> *my_list = new list<event_t*>();
      my_list->push_back(new_event);
      all_events[new_event->table_name] = *my_list;
    }
    else{
      map_it->second.push_back(new_event);
      for (list<event_t*>::iterator list_it=map_it->second.begin(); list_it!=map_it->second.end(); ++list_it)
        std::cout << (*list_it)->event_type << " " << (*list_it)->time_out << " " << (*list_it)->num_of_events_threshold << '\n';
    }


/*
* waiting for number of events reach its threshold.
*/
    pthread_mutex_lock(&new_event->lock);

    while(new_event->num_of_events_so_far < new_event->num_of_events_threshold )
      pthread_cond_wait(&new_event->cond, &new_event->lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&new_event->lock);
    // segmentation fault!!!
    for (list<event_t*>::iterator list_it=map_it->second.begin(); list_it!=map_it->second.end(); ++list_it)
        std::cout << (*list_it)->event_type << " " << (*list_it)->time_out << " " << (*list_it)->num_of_events_threshold << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize your mutex ?

Comment: Yes it has been initialized in constructor of event_t class.

Comment: When you add the new event list to the master-map, you never appear to be setting `map_it` to the newly added entry. Thus when you reach your for-loop and attempt to use the iterator, you're dereferencing `end()`

Comment: Note that comparing two `char *`s only compares the pointers, not contents. Your `map` might not work the way you want.

Comment: I completely concur with avakar's statement to a point. You provide your own comparator, which is good, but honestly none of these should be `char*`. You should ideally be using `std::string`, at which time the default comparator is adequate. And use instance-level lists, not pointers to lists.

Comment: @WhozCraig, ah, I completely missed the custom comparator!

Comment: @avakar not to be alarmed, the premise is just as valid. these should be `std::string` to begin with unless there is a *very* good reason not to do so, and they are indeed rare.

Comment: I can't use std::string because everywhere c-style string is used in this project. and I think it would be a overkill to use c_str().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(map_it == all_events.end()){
  list<event_t*> *my_list = new list<event_t*>();
  my_list->push_back(new_event);
  all_events[new_event->table_name] = *my_list;
}
```

This code doesn't leave `map_it` pointing to a valid iterator, so when you dereference it at the bottom of the function it will crash.

You probably want to add a line like

```
map_it = all_events.find(new_event->table_name);
```

inside the `if { }` clause.

Comment: +1 (for obvious reasons, per my global comment). Alternatively, he can use the `std::pair<iterator,bool>` returned from an `insert()` to reacquire the proper iterator without performing an additional search.

Comment: This solves the problem. However I have another issue which I will try to solve first. Thank you and I can't upvote because I need at least 15 reputation for that.